# Javascript await / promise order of execution is not as expected

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, promise, async-await

In my Nodejs project I would just like to `await` a mongoose.save function before continuing with my code. The below example does not work, but can anyone help me with something that will work please.

```
app.post('/api/CreateUser', async (req, res) => {
    const newUser = new User({
        'email': req.body.email,
        'name': req.body.name
    });
    console.log('before save');
    await newUser.save((err, userDoc) => {
        if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
        console.log('saved item');
    });
    console.log('after save');
});
```

The current console.log order is:

1. before save
2. after save
3. saved item

But I would like it to be:

1. before save
2. saved item
3. after save

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Please change code with `try` and `catch`.

Also, check how to use `await`.

```
try {
  const newUser = new User({
    'email': req.body.email,
    'name': req.body.name
  });
  console.log('before save');
  let saveUser = await newUser.save(); //when fail its goes to catch
  console.log(saveUser); //when success it print.
  console.log('after save');
} catch (err) {
  console.log('err' + err);
  res.status(500).send(err);
}
```

Comment: Dude thank you! I have been battling with this stuff for a while now. Never really used the try/catch stuff

Comment: @IftekharDani Can you please explain why OP's code does not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why OP code does not work as expected is due to how asynchronicity works with JS/Node. The console log is synchronous (in a synchronous statement), so it will fully execute before the save, which takes some amount time, hence its asynchronous. The synchronous code will finish and display first.

Study the event loop carefully, programming in JS properly depends on understanding it.