# Node.JS : Async/Await taking so long and never ending

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to set up an API with MongoDB (Mongoose) with a JWT authentication. I am at the first step where I create an user in the DB.
But I encounter a problem : the async/await taking so long and never ending, while the user is not created on DB. I don't know why.

I'm testing with POSTMAN for requests. For information, when I'm starting my app, I'm getting the "connected to db !" who appear correctly.

Can someone help me please ?

app.js

```js
'use strict';

const express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    authRoutes = require('./routes/auth'),
    externalRoutes = require('./routes/web'),
    database = require('./database/db'),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose = require('mongoose')
;
require('dotenv').config();
var options = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://user:password@host.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority", options, () => console.log('connect to db !'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api/user', authRoutes);
app.use('/', externalRoutes);
app.listen(8080);
```

auth.js

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../database/schemas/User');

router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {

    const user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    });

    const savedUser = await user.save((error, userDoc) => {
        if (error) return res.status(400).send(error);
    });

    res.send({
        user: savedUser._id
    });


}).post('/login', (req, res) => {

});

module.exports = router;
```

User.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
        max: 255
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 255,
        min: 10
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 1024
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832010/mongoose-await-save) can help.

Comment: see docs, https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save *Returns:
«Promise,undefined» Returns undefined if used with callback or a Promise otherwise.*

Comment: it looks like you are trying to return a promise while also using a callback. You need to choose one way instead of doing both

Answer (score 1):

In Auth.js do this instead

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../database/schemas/User');

router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {

    const user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    });

    try {
        // if you are using await, don't pass it a callback
        const savedUser = await user.save();
        return res.send({
            user: savedUser._id
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // use try/catch to handle error instead of error first parameter in callback
        return res.status(400).send(error);
    }

}).post('/login', (req, res) => {

});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is a link to the documentation that shows you how to correctly use the save method. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save