# how to wait for model.save() in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a function like so:

```
createNewUser async (user) {
    const newUser = new User();
     newUser.name = user.name;
     newUser.password = user.password;
     let result = await newUser.save((err, data) => {
         if (err) return err;
         console.log(data);
         return data;
     })
     console.log(result) // Undefined
}
```

The result return undefined and it run BEFORE the console.log(data) which very weird. Is there any way to get the result of newUser.save() either it be error or the data that successfully saved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose await save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832010/mongoose-await-save)

Comment: i saw that before posting this thread but I did not aware that I cannot put callback in there if I want to await it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to use callback if you want to use `async/await` or `promises`.
This moment is clearified in [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save).

So, correct code:

```
async createNewUser (user) {
    const newUser = new User();
    newUser.name = user.name;
    newUser.password = user.password;

    const result = await newUser.save();
    console.log(result); // result
}
```

And if you need to proccess errors (what is strongly recommended, but in your code error handler doesn't do anything), you can just wrap it into `try/catch`:

```
async createNewUser (user) {
    const newUser = new User();
    newUser.name = user.name;
    newUser.password = user.password;

    try {
      const result = await newUser.save();
      console.log(result); // result
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("something goes wrong");
    }
}
```

Comment: `createNewUser async (user) {` This is a syntax error right! async keyword should come before function name right.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're passing a callback to `save` it will no longer return a promise so using `await` doesn't work.

If you want it to return a promise then don't pass a callback and you can use `try-catch` block for detecting errors:

```
const createNewUser = async (user) => {
  const newUser = new User();
  newUser.name = user.name;
  newUser.password = user.password;
  try {
    const result = await newUser.save();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this shortcode too. If you need you can enclose that function in try-catch block.

```
async createNewUser (user) {
    const result = new User({
        name: user.name,
        password: user.password
    });
    console.log(await result.save())
}
```