# node.js async multiple await not working for user signup

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I am trying to reproduce this code using async/await but I can't figure how to

.then.catch chain/nest

```
exports.signup = (req, res, next) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    .then(hash => {
      const user = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hash
      });
      user.save()
        .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: 'Utilisateur créé !' }))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(500).json({ error }));
};
```

What I came up with trying to use async/await

```
exports.signup = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
       const hash = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
       const user = new User({
           email: req.body.email,
           password: hash
       });
       console.log(user);
       let saveUser = await user.save();
       console.log(saveUser);
       res.status(201).json({ message: 'Utilisateur créé !'})
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({e})
    }
};
```

I am getting the user in my console but the code crashes during user.save() since I don't get anything from console.log(saveUser)

I've been reading that you can stack await functions into one try block, but maybe here it doesn't work since you need

I've tried separating the try/catch, requiring me to initialise hash outside of the try block since i'll be using it in the second try but it's also not working.

After editing according to Nil Alfasir's thoughts:

```
exports.signup = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
       const hash = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
       const user = new User({
           email: req.body.email,
           password: hash
       });
       console.log(user);
       user.save();
       return res.status(201).json({ message: 'Utilisateur créé !'})
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(500).json({e})
    }
};
```

But I'm getting this in the console

```
(node:43390) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myFirstDatabase.users index: username_1 dup key: { username: null }
.
.
.
(node:43390) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:43390) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

A few issues:

1. `user.save()` doesn't return any value (according to the first snippet) - and you're trying to save a returned value into `saveUser`
2. Nit: please add a `return` before `res.status...`

**UPDATE**

The "update" of the question totally changed it, please avoid from doing that and post a new question in the future.

Sounds like you must provide a `username` when creating a user because username must be unique, and when you try to create multiple users without a username the DB creates a record with `username=null` so the first one may create but the second one will fail.

Comment: 1. I did not have it before but I was getting errors in the console
2. Okay, I did that because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832010/mongoose-await-save
3. Okay !

Now that I've cleaned to just have user.save(), this is what I get in the console
```
(node:43390) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myFirstDatabase.users index: username_1 dup key: { username: null }
```
I do not have a username field in my user model though

Comment: I found the problem ! I actually already used the MongoDB Atlas cluster previously and already had created a User schema. The old schema required a nickname and I totally forgot about it.

I simply edited my model to create a new collection in mongodb and everything works fine, with or without await in front of user.save()

Comment: @Gradient a "nickname" or a "username" ?

Answer (score 1):

Correcting Nir Alfasi on save async

1. save() **IS** a async function [SAVE ASYNC](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/save#:%7E:text=The%20save()%20method%20is,Mongoose%20insert%20a%20new%20document.&text=If%20you%20load%20an%20existing,updates%20the%20existing%20document%20instead.)

so it won't return anything.

If there's an error it can be caught be catch.

Comment: So I shouldn't write return before the res.status(xxx).json({ }) ?